# Subscribe an observable after parent component finish rendering - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, parameter-passing

I have two related components, in the parent component I am subscribing to get product data

```
getProductData(productId) {
    this.magB1BaseService.getProductById(productId)
      .pipe(
        tap(response => {
          if (response.Success && response.Data != null) {
            this.Product = response.Data as Product;
            console.log('Product Data==>', this.Product);
            this.productMedia = this.Product.Media;
            this.prepareMediaFileList();
            this.getAttributeSetAttributes(this.Product.AttributeSet);
          } else {
            this.notification.error('Error', response.Errors[0]);
          }
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

and passing a value from the product object to child component

```
<app-mag-b1-category
              [(recordValue)]="Product.Categories"
              (AddCategory)="addCategory($event)"
              (DeleteCategory)="deleteCategory($event)">
</app-mag-b1-category>
```

and inside the child component (categoryComponent) I am calling an function to handle the incoming value from the parent.

```
mapRecordValues() {
    if (this.recordValue != null) {
      const selectedCategories = this.recordValue as ProductCategory[];
      selectedCategories.forEach(cat => {
        const category = this.AllCategories.find(x => x.Id === cat.CategoryID);
        const test = this.transformer(category, 1);
        test.selected = true;
        this.selectListSelection.toggle(test);
        this.dataSource._flattenedData.subscribe(data => {
          const obj = data.find(z => z.Id === category.Id);
          if (obj != null) {
            obj.selected = true;
            this.selectListSelection.toggle(obj);
          }
        });
        this.dataSource._expandedData.subscribe(data => {
          const obj = data.find(z => z.Id === category.Id);
          if (obj != null) {
            obj.selected = true;
            this.selectListSelection.toggle(obj);
          }
        });
      });
      this.selectedCategoriesToSend = Object.assign([], this.recordValue);
      this.selectedCategoriesCount = this.selectedCategoriesToSend.length;
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is the  function (MapRecordValues) is being called before the parent component being initialized and the value passed to the child is always null

Comment: I've been forced to use event emitter to emit new values, is it a good approach?

Comment: Where/when is getProductData called?

Comment: @dopoto getProductData is being called in ngOnInit of the parent component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to have [**`ngOnChanges()`**](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges#ngOnChanges) lifecycle method in order get the latest updated input value from parent component.

Try to add it like below,

**category.component.ts :**

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.recordValue.currentValue && changes.recordValue.currentValue.length) {
         this.mapRecordValues();
    }
}
```

Comment: is using this way will affect on the performance ?? because this life hook will be executed every time a variable value will change

Comment: @James.mikael actually, NO. this method is designed to track the input objects and it trigger every time for only those input changes.